# Lightning Component - Updating CPQ QuoteLine Fields via inline editing

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, cpq

I am recently working on a custom lightning component and one of the features is for a table that consists of SBQQ__QuoteLine__c records, and the ability to inline edit a field like Quantity(SBQQ__Quantity__c).

**The issue**

> After I click the save button which initiates the steps below, the
>   final step of server side updating does not happen, it does not error
>   out nor give any indication to why this isn't working.

I am new to CPQ and not sure if this is an object/field related issue, but I have not seen any solution on stack or google that will alleviate this problem.

Long story short I have an aura attribute which houses the list of QuoteLine records, this work fine:

```
<aura:attribute name="currentProducts" type="SBQQ__QuoteLine__c[]" />
```

The particular field I would like to edit is like so, and this works in reflecting the current value of that field on that quote line:

```
<lightning:input value="{!v.view.SBQQ__Quantity__c}" />
```

Upon updating this value, say from 1 to 5, and then clicking the save button, the following method in my lightning controller runs, and this also works fine:

```
saveProducts: function(component, event, helper) {
    var qliString = JSON.stringify(component.get('v.currentProducts'));
    console.log(qliString);
    var action = component.get('c.saveQuoteLineItems');
    action.setParams({
        'lineItems' : qliString
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();                
        } else {
            console.log('Error in saveProducts lightning controller');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

We then move to fire the Apex method, which debugs the correct list of records, with the updated values, like so:

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> saveQuoteLineItems(String lineItems) {
    List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> lst = (List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>)JSON.deserialize(lineItems, List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>.class);


    system.debug('lineItems: ' + lst);
    update lst;
    return lst;
}
```

After the lightning component fires the refresh, the data is still in its updated for, but the server update does not go through, and on a full refresh we are back to square one.

I have tried various things to create new lists of the records and update those, or possibly re-append them to the Quote, and update the quote, or delete the quoteline items and re-insert them on the Quote...but maybe I am missing the forest for the trees, am I doing something wildly obvious here that would lead to the records not being updated?

Sample JSON string passed into Apex class:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"a1729000003o09wAAA",
      "Name":"QL-0000078",
      "SBQQ__ProductOption__c":"a13290000013M5sAAE",
      "SBQQ__ListPrice__c":12,
      "SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c":10,
      "SBQQ__ProductCode__c":"123",
      "SBQQ__ProductName__c":"Another Product",
      "SBQQ__Quantity__c":6,
      "SBQQ__ProductOption__r":{  
         "Name":"PO-000146",
         "Id":"a13290000013M5sAAE"
      },
      "Terminal__c":""
   },
   {  
      "Id":"a1729000004cKVfAAM",
      "Name":"QL-0001471",
      "SBQQ__ListPrice__c":0,
      "SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c":0,
      "SBQQ__ProductName__c":"Kit Kat",
      "SBQQ__Quantity__c":60,
      "Terminal__c":""
   },
   {  
      "Id":"a1729000004cKcWAAU",
      "Name":"QL-0001472",
      "SBQQ__ListPrice__c":0,
      "SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c":0,
      "SBQQ__ProductCode__c":"12345",
      "SBQQ__ProductName__c":"Sample Product Name",
      "SBQQ__Quantity__c":1,
      "Terminal__c":""
   }
]
```

Comment: Are there any product rules/ pricing rules written? You may also want to check if they are resetting the quantities.

Comment: @Stas Christiansen, what does 'qliString' look like when you send it to the server from the client(example JSON)

Comment: @glls I've added the JSON being passed to the apex controller. Shailesh Patil I will check for rules but when I go into the individual record and update the price, it persists, and also when I do it in query editor.